# Loading modules into node.js AWS lambda dynamically from S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have managed to do this, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way. I need to load a module into a node.js (12.x) AWS lambda. There are many possible modules I can load and want to select them dynamically rather than including all in the lambda zip. So I do the following in the lambda:

1. Load file from S3 and save to /tmp/my_module with fs.writeFile
2. require("/tmp/my_module")

This works, but it seems a bit messy. Are there any alternatives? Ideally I would have liked to have used import() rather than require(), but I understand that it's not possible to enable this feature in AWS lambda.

Comment: I'm not aware of any better options. Your solution seems quite reasonable.

Comment: Will the node_modules in /tmp/ deleted or garbage collected by any means? Or will it stay till we remove it ?

Answer (score 3):

AWS let us create "[Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)".

> A layer is a ZIP archive that contains libraries, a custom runtime, or
> other dependencies. With layers, you can use libraries in your
> function without needing to include them in your deployment package.
>
> A layer is a ZIP archive that contains libraries, a custom runtime, or
> other dependencies. With layers, you can use libraries in your
> function without needing to include them in your deployment package

However, layers need to be linked to the lambda at development time. Throught the AWS Cli, Lambda GUI or Serverless Framework.

They can be created with a zip or from a .zip in S3 bucket.

The [structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) for the NodeJS layer is as follows:

> Node.js – nodejs/node_modules, nodejs/node8/node_modules (NODE_PATH)
>
> Example AWS X-Ray SDK for Node.js
>
> xray-sdk.zip
> └ nodejs/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk

Comment: I understand that this is a potential solution, but it isn't "dynamic" in that the lambda has to be updated in order to add modules this way. Either the layer needs to be updated and the lambda changed to the new layer version, or the layer needs to be changed in the lambda configuration (and layers generated per module set in advance). So in short all the modules would need to be preloaded in every run, which is potentially a problem due to size limitations of the layer/lambda. So for my specific use case this is less ideal than loading from S3.

Comment: Do you need to import different modules at runtime or at deployment? If the answer is at runtime, you will be able of achieve that with your solution.

Comment: At runtime, and yes it works, but maybe there are other solutions.